Cargo complaning about unmatchable version requirements with `pyth-solana-receiver-sdk` and `serde_with` crates
I'm Elio, founder at Intrant Inferis Solana mobile RPG
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `serde_with = "^2.3.3"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 1.14.0, 1.13.0, 1.12.1, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `pyth-solana-receiver v0.1.0

I'm tyring to compile my program https://github.com/lopeselio/pyth-crosschain/blob/pyth-solana-stub/target_chains/solana/programs/pyth-solana-receiver/Cargo.toml using cargo clean && cargo build-bpf
I get the above error with crate serde_with which the compiler says is not compatible with pyth-solana-receiver-sdk v0.1.0
Do you know which version of serde_with crate needs to be used?

https://github.com/lopeselio/pyth-crosschain/blob/pyth-solana-stub/target_chains/solana/programs/pyth-solana-receiver/Cargo.toml#L27
edited the cargo.toml file, still get the same error

It's a bit fight for Solana to manage these types of dependency mismatches. But with increasing versions, it happens to be better and better.
When you ask what serde_with crate needs to be used it can be answered from the error message
failed to select a version for the requirement `serde_with = "^2.3.3"`

The dependency resolution requires the version ^2.3.3 (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json/)
When you check the dependencies then you can see there is used Solana in version 1.16.20
https://github.com/lopeselio/pyth-crosschain/blob/pyth-solana-stub/target_chains/solana/Cargo.toml#L25
From that, you can check the version Solana was expected to work on.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.16.20/Cargo.toml#L284
Which is the 2.3.3.

Thanks will, try this now!
